# Can someone tell me the purpose of this multi-tool?

Tags: tool-identification

I just got this in the mail (see picture below). I’m just not sure if it’s a good idea to give it to my 14 year old (at the time of his next birthday) nephew.

In the mean time, could someone tell me what the various pieces actually do? I think that they are mostly fishing items.

[image: image of flat multi-use tool]

Comment: I thought it was a stencil (for drawing), but no.

Comment: Looks like this would fit on our sistersite The Great Outdoors.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is a fishing/survival tool.  To use most of the tools, you snap the needed tool (such as a hook) off the slab.  The individual tools do not reattach.

As you noticed, most of the tools are for fishing, but some are more general tools, such as a saw.

Whether or not its appropriate for your 14 year old nephew, depends largely on his maturity and your best judgement.  Personally, I think it's fine for the typical 14 year old, especially if they like to fish.

As a side-note, unique tools like this can be great for arts and crafts.  For example, some of those tools can be used to create wonderful patterns in clay or can be used with paints similar to how you would use a palette knife.  Obviously, not for little kids due to the small metal parts, but for adults, these types of unique metal shapes can lead to wonderfully unique artistic expressions.

Answer (score 9):

It looks a lot like this:

[image]

From the [product info](https://www.readyman.com/collections/survival-cards/products/readyman-wilderness-survival-card):

> The Wilderness Survival Card is a set of tools and devices that are a game changer for somebody in a survival scenario. With this many survival tools on tap at this price and weight, it's a great value in a wallet-sized package!
>
> What makes this tool so uniquely advantageous is that it weighs less than an ounce, yet can replace up to 20lbs of gear! Put away your bulky fishing lures, that gigantic foldable spear, and awkward hand-saw, and get something that you can carry around in your pocket!
>
> #### Specifications:
>
> - Fits in a Wallet or Altoid Tin (Card Size: 2" x 3.5" in)
> - Weight: 12 Grams / 0.42 oz
>
> #### Features:
>
> - Fishhooks (x9)
> - Arrows (x5)
> - Snare locks (x4)
> - Awl (x1)
> - Sewing Needles (x2)
> - Saw blades (x3)
> - Tweezers (x1 - on the right-hand edge)

Comment: "that gigantic foldable spear" because you never leave the house without one...

Comment: If the OP could confirm or deny the presence of the logos on the other side, it would go a long way towards confirming if this is the correct identification of the tool in question.

Comment: It is not the same tool, (different components,) it can be from the same company and/or the same size.

Comment: @Willeke, other than the additional component on the right side of OP's, what components are different? They seem the same to me, if varying slightly in proportion(and upside down). Could easily be an older and newer iteration of the 'same' tool from the same company.

Comment: I see a four pointed 'fork' just to the left of the middle in the picture of OP, which is not in the one in this post, on the other hand, in the one in this post there is a different item in mostly the same spot. So clearly not the same item. (John in an other answer has found the same item as OP shows, or a better copy that the one in this answer.)

Answer (score 9):

I managed to find the same product on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B087M5NG2Z):

[image]

It's described as "a handy wallet tool [that] contains everything you need to survive":

> This handy wallet tool contains everything you need to survive if you ever run into an emergency situation. Explore the wilderness with the comfort of knowing the Military Grade Survival Tool from has your back!

> Lightweight card brings together a variety of fishing and hunting tools, Clever combination of multiple CARDS.

According to the description it includes:

> Survival Saw (Coarse and Fine Edged)
>
> Fine Saw Sewing Needles(2)
>
> Trident Spearhead Arrowhead
>
> Small Game Arrowhead
>
> Single Fish Hooks (4)
>
> Double Fish Hooks (5)
>
> Snare Hooks/Lures (4)
>
> Awl/Tweezers

[image]